# What is the limit for $e^{\,x-1}$ as $x$ tends to infinity?

Tags: limits

What is the limit $$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} e^{\,x-1} ?$$

Thanks.

Comment: Try plugging in larger and larger values on x on your calculator. What is $e^{100-1}$? $e^{1000-1}$? $e^{10000-1}$, etc. Also, try typing \limits before the _ to get the $x\rightarrow\infty$ under the $\lim$ like this, $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}$

Comment: Are you asking for the value of the limit $\lim_{x\to \infty}e^{x-1}$?  Or are you asking for the value of the limit $\lim_{x\to \infty}e^{x^{-1}}$?

Comment: The edits have already MathJax'ed your question, but maybe not correctly? (@Dr.MV's question points at another interpretation of what you wrote. To avoid things like that happening (and just because it makes math look much nicer than the alternatives), you should learn LaTeX/MathJax, you could start with [MathJax help](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: In the future, you may want to add *context* to your question. What do you *suspect* the limit is? Why aren't you confident in what you think? Are you proving this, or do you just need to know the limit? etc etc

Answer (score 2):

As $x$ tends to infinity, $x-1$ goes toward $+\infty$, therefore: $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}e^{x-1}=\lim_{x\to+\infty}e^x.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}e^{x-1}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{e^{x}}{e}=\frac{1}{e}\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}e^{x}=+\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality that

$$e^x\ge 1+x \tag 2$$

for all $x$.  Therefore, we have

$$e^{x-1}\ge x$$

and hence

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}e^{x-1}\ge \lim_{x\to \infty}x=\infty$$